# Apply discount each time the configured promotion quantity is matched for each item in the order

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how to create a dynamic promotion feature for my restaurant system. E.g. some of the promotions I may have are:

- Buy 1 Milkshake Get 1 Free
- Buy 2 Burgers Get 1 Milkshake Free

Here's what I have so far.

**Database Tables (Model) and example data:**

- items (Item)

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Milkshake | 2.00 |
| 2 | Burger | 4.00 |

- promotions (Promotion)

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Buy 1 Milkshake Get 1 Free | 2.00 |
| 2 | Buy 2 Burgers Get 1 Milkshake Free | 8.00 |

- promotion_items (PromotionItem)

| id | promotion_id | item_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

- orders (Order) *

| id | sub_total | discount_total | final_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8.00 | 4.00 | 4.00 |

- order_items (OrderItem)

| id | order_id | item_id | price | quantity | final_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2.00 | 2 | 4.00 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2.00 | 1 | 2.00 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2.00 | 1 | 2.00 |

***the `orders` table example data is my desired outcome, the discount_total and then final_total haven't been achieved.**

So, in my data examples above, order id 1 has 4 Milkshakes, meaning the 'Buy 1 Milkshake Get 1 Free' (promotion id 1) should be applied twice, making the `orders`.`final_total` equal £4.00 instead of £8.00, using the `promotions`.`price` column.

Here's what I've got so far, please read my code comments to see where I'm stuck:

```
<?php
    public function applyOffer() {

        // There are 4 Milkshakes (item id 1) in this order (order id 1) as shown in my data examples
        $order = Order::with('orderItems.item')->where('id', 1)->firstOrFail();

        // Get all the promotions
        $promotions = Promotion::has('promotionItems')->get();

        $discount_total = 0.00;

        // If promotions are found
        if($promotions->count() > 0) {
            foreach($promotions as $promotion) {

                // The first promotion found would be 'Buy 1 Milkshake Get 1 Free' (promotion id 1) as shown in my data examples

                // Some how use $promotion->promotionItems to match up with $order->orderItems and apply the discount ($promotion->price) the relevant number of times (twice in this case)

                // if(?) {
                    $discount_total = $discount_total + $promotion->price;
                // }

            }
        }

        $order->sub_total = $order->orderItems->sum('final_total');
        $order->discount_total = $discount_total;
        $order->final_total = $order->sub_total - $discount_total;
        $order->save();

    }
?>
```

Extra Info:

The reason my `order_items` data example isn't just 1 row with a quantity of 4 is because sometimes a customer can add different extras e.g. in a Milkshake's case, one might want Semi-Skimmed Milk and another Whole Milk but I've left extras out to try to avoid any unnecessary confusion.

Comment: promotion_items structure has problem. you should identify which product is condition of promotion and which is prize.

Comment: @MohammadJavadGhasemy I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The promotions table contains the price which should be discounted if the promotion_items are matched within order_items, by quantity. What is the stucture problem?

Comment: you should buy 1 MS to get one MS free.
the problem is here. you cant have a promotion like buy 3 MS and get 1 MS free
you should have something to validate orders by promotions.

Comment: @MohammadJavadGhasemy I could set up the stucture for Buy 3 MS get 1 MS free, I would just have to change the milkshake's quantity to 3 in promotion_items (id 1) and change the price to 4.00 in the promotions table (id 1).